# sliding expiration .net session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm trying to allow my users to stay within the website indefinitely, so that if there session hasn't expired yet i will slide the expiration to another few minutes, but it doesn't seem to work.

my code:

```
private void Application_EndRequest(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
        if(Response.Cookies["siteCookie"] != null)
        {
            Response.Cookies["siteCookie"].Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
        }
}
```

but only in the initial request when the end user doesn't have my cookie yet the server returns Set-Cookie header, but not on the requests that follows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Response.Cookies` contains a list of cookies that are being set as part of the current request/response.  It does *not* contain cookies that were set earlier, although those will typically appear in `Request.Cookies`.  So you could use something like this:

```
private void Application_EndRequest(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    var oldCookie = Request.Cookies["SiteCookie"];
    if (oldCookie != null)
    {
        var newCookie = new HttpCookie("SiteCookie", oldCookie.Value);
        newCookie.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
        Response.AppendCookie(newCookie);
    }
}
```